# Nginx basic auth working on http but not on https

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, nginx-location

Im running nginx on centos 6. The domain is configured to use ssl. Some specific folders need to be password protected. If I type the url with http the basic the browsers asks to enter user and pass. If I type the same url with https then the index file of the specific folder will be shown without asking for user pass.

I have this in my domain specific nginx.conf file:

```
  location /protected_folder {
      auth_basic "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
```

How can I make sure that the both urls using http and https are password protected?

Answer (score 1):

I saw that nginx has two config files in the same directory: nxingx.conf and snginx.conf. I simply had to update snginx.conf with the same auth rules and it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your restricted configuration in 80 and 443 ports :

/etc/nginx/sites-available/MY_VHOST

```
server
{
    listen               80;
    server_name          YOUR.FQDN;

.....other config of vhost..... 

    location /protected_folder {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}

server
{
    listen               443;
    server_name          YOUR.FQDN;

.....other config of vhost..... 

    location /protected_folder {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

or you can redirect the http request to https :

```
server
{
        listen               80;
        server_name          YOUR.FQDN;
        return 301           https://YOUR.FQDN$request_uri;

}
server
{
    listen               443;
    server_name          YOUR.FQDN;

.....other config of vhost..... 

    location /protected_folder {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For cloud services like **Cloud Sigma** or **V2**, you have to edit: *nginx/conf.d/ssl.config* to support the authentication over **https**