# Config problem - Serve react app and spring boot backend with http basic-authentication behind nginx https reverse proxy orchested by docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, spring-boot, nginx, https

Him

I’ve got a problem that I can’t solve.

When I query my springboot backend it works fine. The password is asked then when I’m authenticated, I receive the answer.

But, if I first call the front-end, (the basic authentication also works) but the nginx proxy doesn’t forward queries to the spring-boot backend anymore.

Could you please help me to figure out what’s wrong with my config. Do I have forgotten a https setting?

In fact, if I turn ssl off, then it’s working perfectly. And disabling basic authentication with ssl doens't solve the problem.

Thanks for help

Here are some more details:

- I have a react app created with create-react-app tool.
- The app call a spring-boot backend.
- I use docker to run all that stuff.
- I use https to prevent clear-text password of basic authentication.
- I serve my app at this example name: https://myPublicHostname (on port 443)
- The backend must be reachable with this name: https://myPublicHostname/rest/myapi/

Here is my deploying files structure:

```
WebDockerService
\-- my-react-app
    \-- public
    \-- src
    \-- package.json
    \-- default.conf
    \-- Dockerfile
    \-- fullchain.pem
    \-- htpasswd
    \-- privkey.pem
\-- my-api
    \-- my-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    \-- Dockerfile
\-- docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my Docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  frontendwithproxy:
   build: ./my-react-app
   ports: 
     - 80:80
     - 443:443 
  springbootbackend:
   build: ./my-api
   ports:
     - 8080:8080
 networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: netDev
```

Here is “my-react-app” Dockerfile to build nginx server

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:9.11.1 as build
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Production Environment ###
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine

COPY fullchain.pem /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem
COPY privkey.pem /etc/nginx/privkey.pem
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY htpasswd /etc/nginx/conf.d/htpasswd
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here is the default.conf file for nginx

```
server {
    #To redirect http traffic to ssl
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://myPublicHostname$request_uri;
}

server{

    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     myPublicHostname;
    #root containing react app files
    root            /usr/share/nginx/html;

    #Basic authentication enabling
    auth_basic              "Restricted Access!";
    auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/conf.d/htpasswd;

    #SSL Settings
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    #Location for springboot api
    location /rest {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header        X-Forward-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header        X-Nginx-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_pass              http://192.168.1.125:8080;          
    }
}
```

Here is the Dockerfile for the springboot backend

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY my-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/my-api/my-api.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/opt/my-api/my-api.jar", "/opt/my-api/public","/opt/my-api/temp", "/opt/my-api/uploads"]
VOLUME ["/opt/my-api/public","/opt/my-api/temp","/opt/my-api/uploads"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

edit :

nginx is the only entry point. everything that enter has to achieve the basic authentication. I don't activate it on http, because I don't want to allow this potential leak. But basic authentication is not the problem, because when I deactivate it, the problem alway occures.

More surprising, backend "GET" queries that get pictures work fine. The pictures are well displayed. They work into  markup and into browser url field.

But the other GET queries that return zip or other content-type doesn't work. (doesn't work as well in  markup as when typed into the browser).

edit 2 :

In fact, it seems to work. Because when I use a rest client and query my resource on backend, the result is well arriving. Also if I call the backend in code winthin react app, the result arrives.

But when I call the backend with a href on a  like this :

```
<a 
  href={"https://myPublicHostname/rest/my-api/getZipFile?value=1,2,3,4,5"}
  target="_blank"
>
```

then the backend doesn't receive the get query.

So myabe some header are missing!?

Comment: basic auth is enabled on both nginx level and app level?

Comment: basic auth is only enabled on nginx. Backend has no encryption and no authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved like this:

```
<a 
  href="/rest/photo/getZipFile?value=1,2,3" 
  target="_blank"
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
  download="AnyCustomFileName.zip"
>
    ...button
</a>
```

This simple attribute that changes everything :

***download="AnyCustomFileName.zip"***

With it, the browser add different headers, then Nginx achieve to rout it at the right destination.

Works for Edge, Chrome, Samsung internet and Firefox... but Fireforx only works in private sessions.

Answer (score 0):

```
When I query my springboot backend it works fine. The password is asked then when I’m authenticated, I receive the answer.
```

If the authentication is enabled on both nginx and backend , then you will need some way so that nginx can authenticate to backend.

When the nginx tries to access the backend , the backend will timeout for authentication. Maybe the auth info is encrypted and cant be taken out.

First test it with authentication on nginx only ( with SSL ) and turn of the auth on backend.

You can also try to turn off the SSL from nginx to backend.

If the above scenario is not the case , and backend has no auth and SSL then here is one answer with nginx SSL basic auth issue:

[Nginx basic auth working on http but not on https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189919/nginx-basic-auth-working-on-http-but-not-on-https)

so you first need to make sure nginx is configured to ask for password on both http and https , then do the rest of work. You can just test it first on some simple page.

Comment: Hi Ljaz, Thanks for your answer. The auth is only on nginx. Backend has no security layer. I want to delegate it to nginx only. even front-end code has no awareness of authentication and ssl.